# How do I use a custom resolution in The Sims 4?

Tags: the-sims-4

I need the game on 1280x720 in window mode so i can stream with OBS.

Answer (score 2):

You can play your game in full-HD (1920x1080). In OBS there is a setting to downscale your streaming resolution. So you can play in 1080p and stream in 720p.

Video settings - Resolution Downscale: 1.50 (1280x720)